# React-Callback: Arguments are not aligned

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, tslint

```
   private function(event: any) {
        this.setState({
            variable123: event.target.value
        }, () => {
            this.function();
        });
    }
```

With this function i get an error for the line with

```
"=>":
"arguments are not aligned"
```

.

I tried some variations but none worked.

is there syntax i am missing or i wrote wrong?

Comment: what you trying to do calling the function inside the setState?

Comment: TSlint is causing this, I've added an answer, but why are you recursively calling function?

Comment: note that you can run your lint command with `--fix` or `-- --fix` to let the linter show you how it wants it to be. :)

Answer (score 0):

The align rule, with the arguments option set, checks that arguments that start on different lines are horizontally aligned to the same starting column. In your case, setState's first argument,

```
{
  variable123: event.target.value
   }
```

and the second argument the arrow function are not aligned. You could try something like this instead:

```
  private function(event: any) {
    this.setState(
      {
        variable123: event.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.function()
      }
    )
  }
```

see this comment [link](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/742#issuecomment-160734479)